# insert og image link in wordpress post

Tags: plugins, images, shortcode, post-thumbnails, urls

I am trying to extraxct the og:image url is there a wordpress plugin that extract og:image url from an external webpage url
i need a shortcode to insert that image in my post

Comment: Adding an og:image link: yes, SEO plugins let you do that. There may be more specific plugins too.

Comment: But extracting from another page: isn't that easiest to do by hand? I assume you only have a handful of pages you want to update. If not, if you need to do this automatically then yes you can find code that will load and parse an HTML document, then you just need to look for the meta properties in the head block. You can then set whatever property on the postmeta that you're using to store these against your pages, which will depend on how you've implemented this or whichever SEO plugin you've chosen.